# Scale factors in cylindrical coordinates - geometrical meaning

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I am trying to make sense of the scale factors in cylindrical coordinates and their geometrical meaning.
To start with something simpler, begin with Cartesian coordinates:
$$h_x=h_y=h_z=1$$
One can say that the meaning of this is: the scale of coordinate $x$ is the same as the scales of coordinates $y$ and $z$. That is, all three coordinates have equal unit length. Does this make sense?

Now, cylindrical coordinates - $$h_r=h_z=1$$
Then, $r$ and $z$ have the same scale and unit of length. 
Last, $$h_{\theta}=r$$
What would be the geometric interpretation of this? Why $r$? What would be a good "rule of thumb" to explain this last scale factor.

Comment: The arc length of a sector of a circle of radius $r$ that traverses an angle of $d\theta$ is $rd\theta$.